# WordPress add_rewrite_rule() shows 404 not found

Tags: wordpress

In wordPress I have created a page called compare. So when I am doing access that page from browser url I am getting the content. `(http://localhost/task/compare/)`

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^compare/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=250', 'top'); // Here 250 is the page id for compare
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

So when I am trying to access the page in url like

```
http://localhost/task/compare/aa-bb-cc-dd

Its showing 404 not found error.
```

So can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Any help and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate your code and found the error.

The main problem is on the expression '^compare/([0-9]+)/?' because '^task' is missing. The expression should be '**^task/compare/([^/]*)/?**'.

Moreover, you would need to change the expression '([0-9]+)' to accept not only numbers '([^/]*)'.

The following code works for me ( /task/compare/value/  ).

```html
add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^task/compare/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page_id=2', 'top'); // Here 250 is the page id for compare
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Regards.
Ed.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should try flushing the permalinks. See the link below.

https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/

Comment: I have already done that but still its showing 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

You are flushing the permalinks correctly but i think the issue is with your regular expression check it here : https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

in add_rewrite_rule you have added number rejex.

```
add_rewrite_rule('^compare/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=250', 'top');
```

so this function will not work with alphabets, if you want to add alphabets you can add the code as below :

```
add_rewrite_rule('^compare/([a-zA-Z]\w+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=250', 'top');
```

Comment: can you please try to update the permalink. Most probably it will resolve your issue.